# angular ui connected sortable refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I have a strange issue with 2 angular ui sortable.

I would like to use one sortable list as a template list where we can take an item and drop it to a connected list. The correct process will removed the moved item from the template list. I have to avoid that !

I test a lot of solutions but I always have troubles :

1) using draggable for the templates list : I want to keep a sortable list to re-order item if I want.

2) Use clone : I don't want to clone item, I want to keep same reference in case of modifying it, it will be modified everywere

3) Actually the best solution is to restore the removed object  (http://plnkr.co/edit/KGMsh9oNQem1KWqd3x5b?p=preview) : When the event "remove" is called on the template list, I push the moved object to the template list at the same index.

-> Models are corrects but template list is not refreshing !!! If the object is duplicate, it works perfectly but I have to keep the same object reference.

-> If the moved object is restore at a different index in the template list, it works.

Look like if the model is the same, the sortable will not be refreshed.

Hope someone will help me, I can't find any solutions...

EDIT : After making the sortable without ui-sortable, I undertand the ui-sortable directive and I could make my code : http://plnkr.co/edit/ynPyHKjBJpwDBRk9DaF5?p=preview
Modifications : 
- track by id in the loop in index.html
- keep trace of removed element and add it when receiving
- apply before receiving